# Rescuing a buggered console

Tags: console

Once in a while, you'll get some output in your console that causes it to go haywire. In some cases, you can't enter text, in others you can enter text but it looks like the Cyrillic alphabet.

Is there any sort of magical command to get it back on track?

Comment: Feel free to give us some idea of what you're talking about. Just the word "console" isn't a whole lot to go by. You could start by letting us know what OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `reset`?

Comment: Okay this is amazing. Except it's not quite perfect.
I'm in pdb (Python debugger) when this happens and I have to quit the debugger to `reset`. I was hoping for some keyboard ninjitsu (hopefully with Sysrq somehow involved.)

Comment: Well, can you shell out from the debugger to a command prompt (like `!` in vim) ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean `reset`?

Comment: haha :) I guess that was an easy one :)

Comment: Hold on, I don't believe you guys. ;) I've been ignorant of this way too long.

Answer (score 1):

If the terminal has switched to showing letters as VT100 line drawing characters, the classic way to switch it back is to type `echo`<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>⏎</kbd>.  Also, `stty sane` is useful to fix messed up terminal settings.  But as many other answers has pointed out, the `reset` command should fix all of these and it's easier to just remember one command.

Answer (score 0):

Try `reset` :-)